# QML control Loader behavior within its component

Tags: qt, qml

I'm implementing a TreeView. I'm exposing a component highlight for the item selection.

The following code works as expected

**TreeView.qml**

```
Flickable {
    id: root

    property Component highlight: Rectangle {
        color: root.selectedColor
    }

    TreeItem {
        id: tree
        // ...
    }

    Loader {
        id: highlightLoader
        sourceComponent: highlight

        width: root.width
        height: 24
        y: tree.currentItem ? tree.currentItem.mapToItem(tree, 0 ,0).y + tree.anchors.topMargin : 0
        z: 0
        visible: tree.currentItem !== null
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
TreeView {
    id: delegateTreeView
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: treeModel
    selectionEnable: true

    highlight: Item {
        Rectangle {
        color: "pink"
        width: parent.width * 0.9
        height: parent.height
            anchors.left: parent.left
            radius: 60
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "pink"
            width: parent.width * 0.2
            height: parent.height
            anchors.right: parent.right
            radius: 60
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to add animations to the custom delegate, like this:

```
highlight: Item {
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(currentY)

    Behavior on y { SpringAnimation { spring: 2; damping: 0.1 } }

    Rectangle {
        color: "pink"
        width: parent.width * 0.9
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        radius: 60
    }
    Rectangle {
        color: "pink"
        width: parent.width * 0.2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        radius: 60
    }
}
```

That `Behavior` does not work since `y` is referred to the `Item` and it's always 0. If I move `Behavior on y` inside the `Loader` element `highlightLoader` it works as intended.
So how can I control the behavior of a property of the `Loader` within it's item component?  Exposing the y property of the highlight through the TreeView it's not an option, since I would do the same for each property then.

Complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/Daguerreo/QMLTreeView).

Comment: I think in this case the loader should be the parent of the item and you can use targetProperty.name and targetProperty.object on the Behavior to monitor the y value of it from within your delegate.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I can monitor the y just adding in the Loader a currentY property, but that do not allow me to write `Behavior on currentY` in my Item